# Eclipse 4.5.2 with m2e 1.6.2 - Launching delegate

Tags: java-8, launcher, m2e, eclipse-mars

this is not an implementation issue. Whenever I am launching application from Eclipse, I can see in progress tab line "Launching: Launching delegate", which freezes on 62 percent. I tried to profile eclipse, I can see that most time is spent here

```
16,6% - 21 635 ms - 37 hot spot inv. org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.IClasspathManager.getClasspath
16,6% - 21 635 ms - 37 hot spot inv. org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.internal.launching.PDEBundleClasspathResolver.resolveMavenClasspath
16,6% - 21 635 ms - 37 hot spot inv. org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.internal.launching.PDEBundleClasspathResolver.getAdditionalClasspathEntries
16,6% - 21 635 ms - 37 hot spot inv. org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run
```

I started having this "problem"(it is more an inconvenience) after migration to Java 8 and Eclipse Mars. Maven installation remained the same.

Have any of you experienced this problem and solved it? I spent several hours googling without positive outcome. Thanks for answer in advance

I experience this problem with large RCP based server/client desktop application which is built by Maven. "Launching delegate..." delays client startup by two minutes or so, which started being quite annoying overhead